# Angular unit testing with RxJs: Introducing a delay in observable response

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, rxjs

I am trying to unit test a function X. X calls another function,Y, which returns an observable. X calls Y several times. Code in X makes use of forkJoin to ensure that all the observables returned from Y are first completed. So I have to test that part too. I have mocked the call to Y as:

```
spyOn(anotherService, "Y").and.returnValues(of(data1), of(data2));
```

To make things a bit more realistic I want to introduce a delay in Y's response so that there is noticeable time gap between completion of first observable  and second observable, so that forkJoin code in X is tested properly.

How can I introduce a delay here?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the `delay` operator but I would advise against doing so. You shouldn't be testing `forkJoin`, it has already been tested by the creators of RxJS.

But try doing this if you really want it:

```
import { delay } from 'rxs/operators';
.....
spyOn(anotherService, "Y").and.returnValues(of(data1), of(data2).pipe(delay(50)); // add a delay of 50ms like so
```

Usually, adding `delays` (or RxJs time functions) makes it tough to test because you might end up with `One periodic tasks still in queue` or other errors. You may have to take advantage of `fakeAsync` and `tick` if you don't want to wait the whole `50ms`.

Comment: I am not testing forkJoin. I want to test that certain sections of code  is executed after completion of all of the observables.